# Can i return array element with the help of two classes?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
 class Revarray
{
    protected static int[]  reversearray(int h[])
    {

            for(int n:h)
            {
                return n;
            }   
    }
}
public class Check
{
    public static void main(String h[])
    {
        int no[]=new int[5];
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Array Elements");
        for(int i=0;i<no.length;i++)
        {
            no[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        Revarray rev=new Revarray();
        System.out.println("Value of Array are:--"+rev.reversearray(no));
    }
}`
```

here in this code can i return value to the check class ,cause I have little but confusion about this ,Within same class I can return the value but I have to know that can i return using two classes ,and here in revarray If i return n then it is showing me the error like int cant be converted to int[] return n

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. As a side note, there would _not_ be a point of using a loop then just return within the first iteration.

Comment: There is also confusion on your end regarding the usage of keywords such as static and protected. As there is no point in mixing them.

Comment: Point is: this is not programming school where we teach you writing correct java code. You learn Java syntax by carefully studying, not by dropping such a mess here assuming we fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

your reverse array return int, not int array, that's why you get error. you'd better make a loop on array from 0 to n/2  and swap element number i and element n-1-i

Answer (score 0):

To reverse array you need to two indexes: one is for iterating given array and one for iterating new array. The code:

```
package com.stackoverflow.main;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Revarray {
    protected int[] reversearray(int h[]) {
        int[] reverse = new int[h.length];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = h.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reverse[k++] = h[i];
        }
        return reverse;
    }
}

public class Check {
    public static void main(String h[]) {
        int no[] = new int[5];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Array Elements");
        for (int i = 0; i < no.length; i++) {
            no[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        Revarray rev = new Revarray();
        System.out.println("Value of Array are:--" + Arrays.toString(rev.reversearray(no)));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Enter Array Elements
3
4
5
6
7
Value of Array are:--[7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
```

Comment: Here why we use Arrays.toString ()method without this can we write directly rev.revrsearray(no);

Comment: No, to print array it must be used